# crear un Hashmap <clave, list<object>>

Tags: java, object, hashmap

tengo un hashmap  (cuyos valores los recojo de una query) y quiero formar un hashmap con una clave y una lista de objetos (clave,list object) ya que tengo claves repetidas con diferentes objetos.

el código actual que tengo con un hashmap  es el siguiente:

```
Map<String, Object> listaEtiquetas = new HashMap<String, Object>();

while(rs.next()) {

    POS_INI_ETI = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(2));     
    POS_INI = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(3));     
    POS_FIN = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(4)); 
    ETIQUETA = rs.getString(1); 

    Registro objPrueba1 = new Registro(POS_INI, POS_FIN);

    listaEtiquetas.put(ETIQUETA, objPrueba1);

}
```

el objeto es el siguiente:

```
public class Registro {

int posIni;
int posFin;

   public Registro(Integer attr1, Integer attr2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

       posIni = attr1;
       posFin = attr2;
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @rodrigo7 para crear un HasMap con un alista de objetos seria de la siguiente forma:

```
    // Lo mejor sería que utilices el tipo de dato Registro en lugar de Object pero sino seria  Map<String, List<Object>>
    Map<String, List<Registro>> listaEtiquetas = new HashMap<>();
    while(rs.next()) {

        POS_INI_ETI = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(2));
        POS_INI = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(3));
        POS_FIN = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(4));
        ETIQUETA = rs.getString(1);

        Registro objPrueba1 = new Registro(POS_INI, POS_FIN);
        // Si la etiqueta existe agregamos un registro extra.
        if (listaEtiquetas.containsKey(ETIQUETA)){
            listaEtiquetas.get(ETIQUETA).add(objPrueba1);
        }else {
            // Si la etiqueta no existe creamos una lista con capacidad inicial para para 2 para ahorrar memoria
            // y la agregamos al Map.
            List<Registro> nuevaLista = new ArrayList<>(2);
            nuevaLista.add(objPrueba1);
            listaEtiquetas.put(ETIQUETA, nuevaLista);
        }
    }
  // Para obtenerlo lo harías de la siguiente forma
   List<Registro> listaRegistros = listaEtiquetas.get(etiqueta);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! lo he probado y genial!